# Is the 2013 Rozen Maiden "Zurückspulen" anime part of the same original storyline?

Tags: rozen-maiden

The main focus of the 2013 **Rozen Maiden** anime is on a Jun who didn't wind the key, in an alternate universe from the one who wound the key. In several points in the show, these two universes cross paths and are linked via N-field.

My question is, is the universe in this TV series where Jun wound the key the same world/story/canon in which the original Rozen Maiden took place (or even "Träumend")? Or is this just part of a completely different storyline/canon in which there was a Jun that wound the key and the events in that universe were similar but unrelated to any of the previous series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding it's based off the Manga which is canon and it combines the first Manga which focuses on Jun having wound and the second manga in which Jun didn't wind and grew up but is contacted by his younger "wound" self to help stop Kirakishou.

The original anime isn't canon since it has Barasuishou who was created by Enju, Rozen's apprentice as a means to prove his superiority as a doll maker over Rozen by having Barasuishou beat the other Maidens and becoming the strongest doll rather than becoming Alice. At the end, the Rozen Maidens defeated by Barasuishou are taken to Kirakishou by Laplace's Demon, Suigintou comes back to life but keeps the Rozen Mysticas she won while Hina Ichigo remains inside Shinku and Shinku is told by Rozen that there is a way to bring her back and another way to become Alice without the Alice Game.

This is different to the manga as Kirakishou devours Hina Ichigo from the inside to assume her physical form and there is no Barasuishou.