# Is Hinaichigo still alive in the manga?

Tags: rozen-maiden

According to [a fandom wiki site](https://rozenmaiden.fandom.com/wiki/Hinaichigo), Hinaichigo's status is listed as alive in the manga, but deceased in both the 2004 anime and the 2013 anime. I've only watched the 2004 anime (a long time ago), where she loses the ability to move due to her Rosa Mystica being taken by Shinku after her (indirect) link with her medium is severed. In the 2013 anime, which is supposedly more faithful to the manga, she is destroyed from the inside-out and she gives her Rosa Mystica to Shinku before dying.

Is the fandom wiki site correct in stating that she is alive in the manga? Does the manga continue past where the 2013 anime left and involve Hinaichigo returning, or is the site incorrect?

Comment: Kind of related: [Is the 2013 Rozen Maiden “Zurückspulen” anime part of the same original storyline?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5336/2516)

Comment: @AkiTanaka I'm aware of why the manga (and 2013 anime by extension) differ from the 2004 anime. The authors got sick, halting the manga and delaying the source work for the anime mid-production, necessitating that the studio finish the story on their own (they did so brilliantly, in my opinion).